# my association is not showing in my rest API built in Sequelize and nodejs and express where I have defined the association in the database

Tags: node.js, rest, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to show the table of star category in my stars table when I call the url in postman, here I'm trying to define that the star category has one too many relationships with stars, and the star belongs to the star category. When I call the get method of stars even though I think I have defined the relationship it will load the validation of stars cannot be loaded instead of  displaying the star recorded then its associated variables  regarding what the star belongs to

```
'star model'
    'use strict';
    const {
      Model
    } = require('sequelize');
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      class Star extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
          // define association here
           Star.belongsTo(models.star_Categories,
               {
                 foreignKey:{
                   allowNull:false
                 }
             })
        }
      };
      Star.init({
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        discovery_name: DataTypes.STRING,
        imageFileName: DataTypes.STRING,
        datediscovered: DataTypes.DATE,
        colour: DataTypes.STRING,
        mass: DataTypes.NUMERIC,
        dfe: DataTypes.NUMERIC,
        galaxy_origin: DataTypes.STRING,
        star_categories_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
      }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'Star',
      });
      return Star;
    };
```

'star_Categories model'

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class star_Categories extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here


       star_Categories.hasMany(models.Star,{
        onDelete:'CASCADE',
         onUpdate:'CASCADE'
       })


    }
  };
  star_Categories.init({
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'star_Categories',
  });
  return star_Categories;
};
```

---

'star Controller'

```
//define all the logic regarding post
//import to our models
const models = require('../models');
//new method to insert star records
function saveStar(req, res){    //creates a star
    //create a new object to insert into the table
    const star = {
        name: req.body.name, //i want to get the name from the incoming request
        discovery_name: req.body.discovery_name,
        imageFileName: req.body.imageFileName,
        datediscovered: req.body.datediscovered,
        colour: req.body.colour,
        mass: req.body.mass,
        dfe: req.body.dfe, //distance from Earth
        galaxy_origin: req.body.galaxy_origin,
        star_categories_id:req.body.star_categories_id
    }

    // const star_Categories = {
    //     type: req.body.type, //i want to get the name from the incoming request
    //     description: req.body.description
    // }


 //select the star model
    //create star record
 models.Star.create(star).then(result =>{
 res.status(201).json({
    message: "Star created good job ",
     star: result
 });
     //if error
 }).catch(error =>{
     res.status(505).json({
         message: "Star cannot be created ",
         error: error
     });

 });

}

//this function will show the data to the user
function showStars(req, res){
   //to get an record we need and id of it
    const id = req.params.id; //here we can get the id

    models.Star.findByPk(id).then(result => {
         res.status(200).json({
            starss:result});  //successful response
         //if this returns an error
    }).catch(error => {
       res.status(500).json({
           message: "star id has not been found",
           error:error
       })
    });

}
// {include:['star_categories']}


function showAllstars(req, res){
  models.Star.findAll().then(result =>{
      res.status(200).json({
          starss:result
      });
  }).catch(error => {  //if there is an error
          res.status(500).json({
            message:"the stars cannot be loaded"
          });
  });



}

function  starUpdate(req,res){
//to update the star we need the star id
    const id = req.params.id; //here we can get the id
    const updatedStar = {
        //this will display the updated star details
        name: req.body.name, //i want to get the name from the incoming request
        discovery_name: req.body.discovery_name,
        imageFileName: req.body.imageFileName,
        datediscovered: req.body.datediscovered,
        colour: req.body.colour,
        mass: req.body.mass,
        dfe: req.body.dfe, //distance from Earth
        galaxy_origin: req.body.galaxy_origin,
        star_categories_id:req.body.star_categories_id
    }
    //this is how the star will be updated, where the id = to the id requested
    //column name and column value
    models.Star.update(updatedStar,{where:{id:id}}).then(result =>{  //passing what we want to update
        res.status(200).json({
            message:"Star Updated successfully ",
            // starss:result,
            star:updatedStar

        });
    }).catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({
            message:"error updating the star make sure you specify the correct id that exists ",
            error:error
        });

    })

}

function killStar(req,res){
//we need to find the star id to delete the star
    const id = req.params.id; //here we can get the id
//find where the id is to delete the record
    models.Star.destroy({where:{id:id}}).then(result =>{
        res.status(200).json({
            message:"you have just killed a star you monster! ",
            star:result
        });

    }).catch(error=> {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: "error updating the star make sure you specify the correct id that exists ",
            error: error
        });
    });
}


//export methods so other files can use these methods
module.exports ={
    //to use the save method we are going to export
    saveStar:saveStar,
    showStars:showStars,
    showAllstars:showAllstars,
    starUpdate:starUpdate,
    killStar:killStar


    // index: index

}


// function index(req, res){
// //list all the stars on our database
//     const stars = "Stars list";
//     res.send(stars); //pass the star string
// }
//n
```